# How to make PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests in Yandex Tank?

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

Documentation says how to make GET/POST requests in Yandex Tank, but I couldn't find instructions about other http requests (PUT/PATCH/DELETE).

Can Yandex Tank shoot with these methods as well and if so, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use phantom (default load generator), make Request-style ammo file with a sequence of http request that you need.
https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#request-style

There were examples of ammo generators https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ammo_generators.html